# Isabelle's document preparation

Tags: latex, isabelle

I would like to obtain the LaTeX code associated with [this theory](https://github.com/rjraya/Isabelle/blob/master/curves/Hales.thy). Previous answers only provide links to the documentation. Let me describe what I did.

I went to the directory of `Hales.thy` and executed `isabelle mkroot`, followed by `isabelle build -D .`, which generated a file named document and a `*.pdf` file which was suspiciously (nearly) empty. Modifications of this command by adding `Hales.thy` as a parameter didn't succeed.

I would appreciate if someone could describe briefly the commands needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. As a precaution, copy the file Hales.thy into a new directory that does not contain any other files and run `isabelle mkroot` again.
2. If I understand correctly, your theory contains `sorry`. In this case, for the build to succeed you need to enable the `quick_and_dirty` mode. For this, before the first occurrence of `sorry` in your theory file, you need to insert `declare [[quick_and_dirty=true]]`.
3. Your theory contains raw text that is not suitably formatted. Try replacing the relevant lines with the following: `text‹The case \<^text>‹t^2 = 1› corresponds to a product of intersecting lines which cannot be a group›` and `text‹The case \<^text>‹t = 0› corresponds to a circle which has been treated before›`.
4. Once this is done, you should be able to use the `ROOT` file in the appendix below. As you can see, I have specified the theory file explicitly and also added the relevant imported sessions.

---

**Appendix**

```
session Hales = HOL +
  options [document = pdf, document_output = "output"]
sessions
  "HOL-Library"
  "HOL-Algebra"
theories
  "Hales"
document_files
  "root.tex"
```

Comment: The specifications of the LaTeX commands introduced by Isabelle during the build process should be scattered around the relevant auto-generated *.sty files. Do you see files like `isabelle.sty` and `isabellesym.sty` in the same directory with `Hales.tex`? If so, then, provided they are included using `\usepackage`, LaTeX should recognise them. I am curious as to what exactly is that you are trying to do... Have you encountered any problems with the build process after following through 1-4?

Comment: By the way, if it make sense for you, I would like to acknowledge your help in the section I'm writing on the proof, but I would need the real name...

Comment: Thank you. As I mentioned before, I do not seek any attribution. You can provide the links to the relevant posts on SO in the comments in the code if you like. However, in my view, they should not appear in the formal proof documents (i.e. the generated *.pdf files). As for my identity, I am not really hiding it from anyone in particular, only from the general public. If you are interested, feel free to drop me an email and ask explicitly and I will provide it (I had to do this on a couple of occasions, so, I guess, by now, there are quite a few people who know it anyway).