# How to build session in Isabelle. (An example for AFP)

Tags: isabelle

I want to make a submission, so I downloaded this example:
https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Example-Submission.html

How to compile it? This is my main aim. Maybe a description may contain such command?

I've tried to find the answer here:
http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/system.pdf
But it contains strange lines, rectangles and circle instead of examples. I don't understand them.
So how one can compile this particular session in Isabelle?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boxes describe the syntax of the ROOT file.

You have to read Section 2.3 of the document to know how to compile the document, but in short:

```
isabelle build -o browser_info -o document=pdf -d /path/to/Example-Submission Example-Submission
```

Comment: It gives output "Running Example-Submission ...
Finished Example-Submission (0:00:04 elapsed time, 0:00:05 cpu time, factor 1.20)
0:00:10 elapsed time, 0:00:05 cpu time, factor 0.50"
But not a single file was generated... Where is a PDF? Not in the /document/, nowhere.  Maybe I have broken installation of Isabelle.

Comment: By default the output should be in `~/.isabelle/Isabelle2020/browser_info/AFP/Example-Submission/document.pdf`. You can generate the output in the same folder with the `document_output` option: `isabelle build -D . -v -c -o document=pdf -o document_output=output`.

Comment: @ged A few more comments. "But it contains strange lines, rectangles and circle instead of examples...": these are known as railroad diagrams (or syntax diagrams). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram and Section 4.5 in Isar-ref. Also, I wanted to mention that I answered a similar question on SO some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57444458/isabelles-document-preparation/57445292#57445292.